Why I cannot Run Old android software on modern android devices?
Dalvil Runtime has discontinued for many years.
why when I try to install an old software on new modern devices it works for mintues or seconds and, then crash. What is the main reason of crashing?
I am trying to understand the techincal issue that related to the programming.

Old apps may use old APIs that have since been discontinued because of security (or other) concerns. So they may work until they try to access those

On my experience, in newer Android SDK Google introduced new permissions and ditched some old permissions. And in my old code, if I request permissions directly from the user, when app runs on new OS, app crashed.
